# Use PHP redirector to return open graph metatags

Tags: php, redirect, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I’m creating a mobile website, and I’ve placed the Facebook Like button on it. See http://www.rwponline.nl/test/ for the test version.

The root of the website contains a PHP file, which checks if users are redirected to /desktop/index.php or to /mobile/index.php

On the test website, you'll find the ‘Verzenden’ button (that is share in Dutch) in the right lower corner. Once clicked, the popup wants to share http://www.rwponline.nl/desktop/ However, I would like to share the main directory (www.rwponline.nl) so that new visitors will always be redirected to the appropriate website. This is the code for the like button:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.rwponline.nl" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

I know that Facebook is looking for the OG metatags, so in this redirecting PHP file on the root of the website, I’m returing the required headers before executing the redirect. See the code below.

```
  if($redirect = ($mobile_browser==true) ? $mobileredirect : $desktopredirect){
header('<meta property="og:title" content="RWP Audio & Lighting"/>');
header('<meta property="og:description" content="RWP Audio &#38; Lighting weet van elk evenement een sfeervolle happening te maken!"/>');
header('<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>');
header('<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rwponline.nl/test/images/icon150.png"/>');
header('<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rwponline.nl"/>');
header('<meta property="og:site_name" content="RWP Audio & Lighting"/>');
header('<meta property="fb:admins" content="RWPOnline"/>');
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header('Location: '.$redirect); // redirect to the right url for this device
exit;
```

I've tried to change the HTTP status code (e.g. 200, or 204) without success. Also testing this on the Facebook Developpers page (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rwponline.nl%2Ftest%2F) doesn’t give me a clue of what’s wrong. Can anyone help me? Or is there something I have overlooked?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't send HTML meta tags as HTTP headers.

Comment: Wow, that's fast! Thanks. Do you have any suggestions on how I can have people 'like' the redirecting PHP file?

Comment: Only by _not_ redirecting from there, when the Facebook scraper visits that resource, so that he thinks it is a “real” page. So either check for the user agent/IP address of the scraper; or do your redirect client-side via JS.

Comment: Thanks, CBroe! I'll have to go with JS then, although I've read the JS redirects are less reliable for mobile phones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780212/php-redirect-url-with-og-metatag-open-graph