# php redirect url with og metatag (open graph)

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, facebook-opengraph

I have server side redirect page in PHP `redirect.php` this page redirects the user with PHP `header()` function:

```
header( 'location: mypage.html?test' );
```

Is there a way to add some OG meta tags (Open Graph) in a way that when someone shares the `redirect.php` page on Facebook and similar websites, these properties would be applied?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Facebook should load this when shared redirect.php"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Since `redirect.php` redirects in every visit, it would be impossible. However, we can allow Facebook Debugger to read the page OG meta tags as below

PHP

```
<?php
if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], array(
  'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)',
  'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
))) {
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  print '<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
               <head>
                  <title>{title}</title>
                  <meta property="og:title" content="{OG Title}" />
                  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
                  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
                  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/og_img.jpg" />
              </head>
        </html>';
}
else {
  // You're not Facebook agent '__' 
  header('Location: mypage.html?test');
}
```

Reference

- [How to recognize Facebook User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8626828/2151050)