# Is it possible to specify Facebook OG meta tags in a php redirect page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a php file which redirects users to another page and grabs the referring website.

```
    <?php
$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$url = base64_encode($ref);
header( 'Location: http://link in here.com/?url=' . $url );
?>
```

The URL where this redirect page lives needs to be posted on Facebook, and so ideally needs OG meta tags to make it look nicer (image, title text etc)

I am no expert, but have played around a bit trying to put these tags below the php, in the php etc but with no joy. I'd imagine it needs to go in the php but before the header redirect?

Is this something that can be done? Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: FB will follow the redirect and ignore the content of the current page - as expected.

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22781663/2151050

Comment: I would suggest redirecting with JavaScript, or with meta refresh tag. Modifying output just for bots can be penalized.

Answer (score 0):

What if you were to try a header refresh.

```
header('Refresh: 0; url=http://link in here.com?url=' . $url);
```

Then you should be able to set the meta tags.

```
<?php
$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$url = base64_encode($ref);
header('Refresh: 0; url=http://link in here.com?url=' . $url);
?>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://link in here.com/img.png"/>
```